# How to fix pixelated painting in Substance Painter on model from Blender

Tags: texturing

I have downloaded a mesh from the internet and make some changes in Blender. When I export it to FBX from Blender and open in Substance painter to create some textures, there is not sharp painting. Image below.
[image: not sharp painting]

But if I create UV sphere in blender from scratch with almost equal number of polygons, the painting is sharp.

[image]

How could I fix the mesh in Blender to get sharp painting?
I tried the *Shade Falt* and *Reset Vectors* in *Edit mode*. Neither helped.

**UPD1.** Attaching .blend with mesh which is pixelated in Substance Painter when I try to paint something. https://drive.google.com/file/d/13AzCBw_Hqjx8waYkMNTghnQz8Z27XDIm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, the image resolution has nothing to do with the amount of faces. Maybe the problem is the image resolution?

Comment: @moonboots Hi, thanks for your response. Not sure what you mean by image resolution. I've set 1024 textures size for both. Yes, when I change 1024 to 2k or 4k, the pixelated image is getting better, but not good enough. It seems just pseudo improve. The root cause is something else...

Comment: Could you please share the object with its image texture?

Comment: @moonboots I've updated my post above. Please find the link. It is blend file. I don't have any materials yet. That's why I'm asking about mesh. I'm exporting this mesh as .FBX from blender and open it in Substance

Comment: See your UVs in the UV Editor, they are very small, scale them up and paint again, you should have a better resolution  @Dron4K

Comment: @moonboots wow, it's helped. Thank you very much man

Comment: Also maybe you should unwrap again, choose the Smart UV Project option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your UVs in the *UV Editor*, they are very small, scale them up, or unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* option so that you have less face distortions, and paint again, you should have a better resolution:

[image]